# DebuggerStepThrough attribute equivalent for properties?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

The `DebuggerStepThrough` attribute instructs the **VS** debugger to step through code instead of stepping into the code.

**[DebuggerStepThroughAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

My question is, is there an equivalent of this attribute to use it for a `Property` member?, because the setter of my property can throw an exception, and I don't want to break in the setter's code-block when that happens.

I know one solution is to move the setter's code to a single method and then set the `DebuggerStepThrough` attribute to that method, but I'm just asking for a possible alternative applying another attribute instead of moving code.

Comment: Tools - Options - Debugger, *Step Over properties and operators*

Comment: Thankyou, I didn't knew it, but I would like to have control of this behavior only for some properties and not for all properties, then is that possible writting code?.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21713385/1070452   (no)

Comment: A property shouldn't really contain so much code that it needs debugging.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can actually apply this attribute directly to the getter and setter.

```
Dim firstName, lastName As String 
Property fullName() As String 
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Get 
      If lastName = "" Then 
          Return firstName
      Else 
          Return firstName & " " & lastName
      End If 

    End Get 

    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        Dim space As Integer = Value.IndexOf(" ")
        If space < 0 Then
            firstName = Value
            lastName = "" 
        Else
            firstName = Value.Substring(0, space)
            lastName = Value.Substring(space + 1)
        End If 
    End Set 
End Property
```

This is the same for C#.

Comment: This is why I should always wait for a second opinnion when asking a question. just thanks! I didn't noticed that easy thing of applying the attribute in the setter.

Comment: No problem. The getter and setter are just syntactic sugar for methods that the compiler creates for you. So you can apply just about any attributes for a method to them. Notably, those that instruct code-coverage tools to ignore them. :)